# Can not get data from service using angular 1.6 with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-http

I have a problem with accessing data from Service in Controller.
Here`s my Service's file code:

```
import {IHttpService} from 'Angular';

export class MyService {
public static $inject = ['$http'];
constructor(private $http:IHttpService, private getItems){

this.getItems= function() {
  this.$http.get('items.json').then(function(response){
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  });
}}}
```

And Controller`s file code:

```
import {MyService} from './MyService';
export class MyController {
public:getData;
static inject: Array<string> = ['$http', '$scope', 'MyService'];
constructor(private $http:ng.IHttpService, private $scope:any, private MyService:any){
    this.getData = function(){
      MyService.getItems.then(function (data) {
      this.getItems = data;

      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Can anybody explain me what`s wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change function declaration to either in below way or use `Arrow` function so that the `this`(context) of class would be preserve. Also you must return `$http` promise from `getItems` method, otherwise you can not apply `.then` method over it to chain promise.

```
getItems() {
  //return promise here.
  return this.$http.get('items.json').then((response) => {
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(response.data);
    //returning data to chained promise.
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Downvoter would you mind to say, why you downvoted? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Return the promise inside the getItems method, It should be,

```
this.getItems= function() {
  return this.$http.get('items.json').then(function(response){
    if(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  });
}}}
```